# Rails process POST request with JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, post

My app receives a third party POST callback from the HelloSign API with event data.

Problem is, I can't seem to get "inside" the json to parse it and save the data.

```
class HelloSignController < ApplicationController
  def receives_data
    j = params[:json]
    logger.info('THIS IS JSON:  ' + j)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: "Hello API Event Received",
                           status: :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

The event data received from params[:json]:

```
{
"event": {
    "event_type": "signature_request_sent",
    "event_time": "1394642012",
    "event_hash": "xxxxx"
},
"account_guid": null,
"client_id": "xxxx",
"signature_request": {
    "signature_request_id": "xxxxxxx",
    "title": "Review Agreement",
    "original_title": "Review Agreement",
    "message": null,
    "test_mode": true,
    "is_complete": false,
    "final_copy_uri": "/v3/signature_request/final_copy/xxxxx",
    "files_url": "https://api.hellosign.com/apiapp.php/v3/signature_request/files/xxxxx",
    "details_url": "https://www.hellosign.com/home/manage?locate=xxxxx",
    "requester_email_address": "xxxxxxx",
    "signatures": [
        {
            "signature_id": "xxxxx",
            "has_pin": false,
            "signer_email_address": "xxxx@gmail.com",
            "signer_name": "admin",
            "order": null,
            "status_code": "awaiting_signature",
            "signed_at": null,
            "last_viewed_at": null,
            "last_reminded_at": null
        }
    ]
}
}
```

How can I parse "j" to save the "event_type" and the "signature_request_id" for example?

Thanks

Also: this is the actual callback from the console:

```
 Started POST "/hs_callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-12 13:32:38 -0400
 Processing by HelloSignController#receives_data as */*
 Parameters: {"json"=>"{\"event\":{\"event_type\":\"signature_request_sent\",\"event_time\":\"1394645254\",\"event_hash\":\"xxxxx\",\"event_metadata\":{\"related_signature_id\":\"\",\"reported_for_account_id\":null,\"reported_for_app_id\":\"xxxxx\",\"event_message\":null}},\"account_guid\":null,\"client_id\":\"xxxxx\",\"signature_request\":{\"signature_request_id\":\"xxxx\",\"title\":\"Review Agreement\",\"original_title\":\"Review Agreement\",\"subject\":null,\"message\":null,\"test_mode\":true,\"is_complete\":false,\"has_error\":false,\"custom_fields\":[],\"response_data\":[],\"signing_url\":null,\"signing_redirect_url\":null,\"final_copy_uri\":\"\\/v3\\/signature_request\\/final_copy\\/xxxxxx\",\"files_url\":\"https:\\/\\/api.hellosign.com\\/apiapp.php\\/v3\\/signature_request\\/files\\/xxxxxxx\",\"details_url\":\"https:\\/\\/www.hellosign.com\\/home\\/manage?locate=xxxxxx\",\"requester_email_address\":\"xxxxx@maildrop.cc\",\"signatures\":[{\"signature_id\":\"xxxxx\",\"has_pin\":false,\"signer_email_address\":\"xxxxxx@gmail.com\",\"signer_name\":\"xxxxxxx\",\"order\":null,\"status_code\":\"awaiting_signature\",\"signed_at\":null,\"last_viewed_at\":null,\"last_reminded_at\":null}],\"cc_email_addresses\":[]}}"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```ruby
j = JSON.parse(params[:json])
j['event']['event_type'] # => "signature_request_sent"
j['signature_request']['signature_request_id'] # => "xxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse`.

```
require 'json'

#in your code 
json_data = JSON.parse(params[:json])
```

This will parse the json data and return a `hash` for it, which you can further read to get all the variables `POST`ed.

For example, to get the account_id, use `json_data["client_id"]`, to get the `signature_id`, use `json_data["signature_request"]["signatrues"][0]["signature_id"]`, and so on.